# Extend SAS MACRO to multiple fields

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro inspired by "PROC SQL by Example" that finds duplicate rows based on a single column/field:

```
data have ; 
input name $ term $; 
cards;
Joe   2000 
Joe   2000 
Joe   2002
Joe   2008 
Sally 2001
Sally 2003
; run; 

%MACRO DUPS(LIB, TABLE, GROUPBY) ; 
  PROC SQL ; 
  CREATE TABLE DUPROWS AS 
   SELECT  &GROUPBY, COUNT(*) AS Duplicate_Rows
   FROM &LIB..&TABLE
    GROUP BY &GROUPBY
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    ORDER BY Duplicate_Rows; 
QUIT; 
%MEND DUPS ;

%DUPS(WORK,have,name) ; 
proc print data=duprows ; run;
```

[image]

I would like to extend this to look for duplicates based on multiple columns (Rows 1 and 2 in my example), but still be flexible enough to deal with a single column.

In this case it would run the code:

```
proc sql ; 
create table duprows as select name,term,count(*) as Duplicate_Rows
from work.have
group by name,term
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
;quit;
```

To produce:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include an arbitrary number of fields to group on, you can list them all in the `groupby` macro parameter, but the list must be comma-delimited and surrounded by `%quote()`. Otherwise SAS will see the commas and think you're providing more macro parameters.

So in your case, your macro call would be:

```
%dups(lib = work, table = have, groupby = %quote(name, term));
```

Since `&groupby` is included in the `select` and `group by` clauses, all fields listed will appear in the output and will be used for grouping. This is because when `&groupby` resolves, it becomes the text `name, term`.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to pass a quoted string and use unquote.  I think this works very well, though, and will serve my purposes.